# Potential difference between conductors

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, capacitance, voltage

Reading some books there is something that i don't understand. Is the capacitors topics when they name a potential difference between conductors.
As i know, Potential difference is the difference in electric potential energy per unit charge between two points.

So, talking about capacitors, the potential difference between conductors is:

```
a) The difference between the potential of each conductor.
b) The difference of potential between those 2 points: (conductor)·     ·(conductor)
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, what are you asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electrical conductors are [equipotential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipotential) surfaces. So both of your choices give the same answer.

Comment: But which would be the correct analogy?

Comment: Analogy to what?

Comment: Sorry, its so hard to explain, i mean, which one would be your first thought about potential difference between conductors.

Comment: I am lost. Both your choices are correct for the case of conductors. So what is the confusion here?